# Deactivate function update on toggle with jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle

I want to show or hide preview content on a click. So I use toggle effect with jQuery.
But I can not hide the preview, if it was activated by a first click.

Here is my jQuery code...

```
$("#show").click(function () {
    $('#editor').toggle();
    $('#preview').hide();
    $("#rte").keypress(update);

    function update() {
        $('#preview').slideDown('slow');
        var rte = $('#rte').val();
        $('#preview_content').html(rte);
    }
});
```

You can see my complete code in action to [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TwgkC/12/).

Thanks very much for your help.

Regards,

Vincent

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you bind the keypress event every time you click on Show.
Try something like this:

```
var doUpdate = false;

function update()
{
    if (doUpdate) {
      $('#preview').slideDown('slow');   
      var rte = $('#rte').val();
      $('#preview_content').html(rte);
    }
}

$("#rte").keypress(update);

$("#show").click(function()
{
  $('#editor').toggle();
  $('#preview').hide();
  doUpdate = !doUpdate;
})
```

Comment: @dioslaka. Thanks, it works! @Yngve B. Nilsen. Sorry, my English is very poor and my ask was not simple to describe. @mVChr Thanks to edit. I don'forget your great function `for (var p in smileDict)`. :) I have updated my Fiddle example with dioslaska's suggest. Cheers.